# Grep Results in new line after a match

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I am using this command to get grep info from a file

```
more filename.txt | egrep 'Name:|matchA:|matchB:'
```

The output is like this

```
Name:Tom
matchA:a
matchB:b
Name:Joe
matchA:a
matchB:b
Name:John
matchA:a
matchB:b
Name:Harris
matchA:a
matchB:b
```

I want the output to be like this

```
Name:Tom matchA:a matchB:b
Name:Joe matchA:a matchB:b
Name:John matchA:a matchB:b
Name:Harris matchA:a matchB:b
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add your sample input in question

Comment: You can pipe your current output to `pr -3ats' '` but yeah, showing your input contents and explaining the logic behind your `grep` command can help to get better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try following `sed` code.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nm/ m/gm'
```

So you should type this in your console

```
more filename.txt | egrep 'Name:|matchA:|matchB:' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nm/ m/gm'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your file-input you can just do:

```
$ join -sd '  \n' file
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%3?OFS:RS)}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts, please try following `awk` code once.

```
awk '
/Name:/{
  if(value){ print value }
  value=$0
  next
}
/matchA:|matchB:/{
  value=value OFS $0
}
END{
  if(value){ print value }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/Name:/{                          ##Checking condition if line contains Name: then do following.
  if(value){ print value }        ##Checking if value is SET then print value here.
  value=$0                        ##Creating value which has current line to it.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/matchA:|matchB:/{                ##Checking condition if line contains matchA: OR matchB: then do following.
  value=value OFS $0              ##Creating value which has current line in it.
}
END{                              ##Starting END block from here.
  if(value){ print value }        ##Checking if value is SET then print value here.
}
' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v ORS= '
    /Name:/ { print nl $0; nl=RS }
    /match[AB]:/ { print OFS $0 }
    END { print nl }
' filename.txt
Name:Tom matchA:a matchB:b
Name:Joe matchA:a matchB:b
Name:John matchA:a matchB:b
Name:Harris matchA:a matchB:b
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F: ' /Name:/ { if(t==1) print ""; printf $0 " ";t=0; next } !/Name:/{ printf $0 " ";t=1 } END {print "" }' data.txt
Name:Tom matchA:a matchB:b
Name:Joe matchA:a matchB:b
Name:John matchA:a matchB:b
Name:Harris matchA:a matchB:b
$
```